# Exercise with Circle Permutations in Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

I have a problem in solving an exercise. It says:

$10$ cars are about to park in a circle plaza, which $3$ of them are cars of permanent residents. In how many ways can the cars be put so as to:

a) None of the permanent residents' cars are parked in consecutive places with an another permanent resident's car ?

b) At least $2$ permanent residents' cars are parked in consecutive places ?

I translated the exercise from Greek so I apologise in advance if I have not phrased something correctly.

**My thought :**

a) From the total of 10 cars, 3 of them belong to permanent residents and the other 7 to "temporary" residents so I will refer to them from now on with $P$ and $T$ respectively.

It is obvious that we have a case of circular arrangement here ( I think that's how is called in English). We need a part of the elements of the circle to be always arranged in a specific way so I considered it a good idea to create a group of objects : $G = (PTPTP)$ which consists of the $3$ $P$ cars and any $2$ of the $7$ $T$ cars and with that if my thinking is correct we have to calculate the number of circles of 6 objects $(T,T,T,T,T,G)$ and multiply the result with $3!*\frac{7!}{5!}$ which I think that they are the circles of the group. That gets me $5!*3!*6*7$ which is far away from the answer of the book which is $6!*\frac{7!}{4!}$. Obviously I'm making something wrong.

b) I have no clue on how to solve b) any hint or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Now, I believe that I know what you mean when you say "circle square", but keep in mind that this is a math forum. We will think of "square" as a rectangle with equal sides before we think of "square" as a plaza.

Comment: Didn't have that thought when I was translating, I'm going to edit it and put plaza to avoid confusion.

Comment: To be clear, in our circular plaza, do we care which direction north is?  I.e. if we label the cars $1,2,3,\dots$ and we start listing which car parked where from the northernmost space going clockwise is the parking sequence $(1,2,3,\dots,9,10)$ considered the same or different than the parking sequence $(2,3,4,\dots,10,1)$?

Comment: JMoravitz I think it's considered the same since we're talking for circle permutations and not simple ones

Comment: LuxGiammi correct answer for b is $9!-6!*\frac{7!}{4!}$ forgot to add it

Comment: Sorry, I did not take into account one detail, and my comment contained a wrong answer.

Comment: Assuming the answer to my above question for clarification is that they are considered the same, a common tactic is to let one person be considered "special" for the purposes of the problem and orient ourselves based on their position.  For the first problem, suppose that Mr. X is one of the permanent residents and suppose WLOG that he parked in the northernmost space.  You can then pick in what order the non-permanent residents appear and then have the two other permanent residents squeeze inbetween.  This gives a total of $7!\binom{6}{2}\cdot 2$ which should match the given answer.

Comment: As for part (b), notice that the if it is not true that no permanent residents are adjacent then it must be true that at least two permanent residents are adjacent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a, I don't understand your logic.  You are missing configurations like $PTTPTTPTTT$.  Let us attach a $T$ after each $P$.  We can do that in $7\cdot 6 \cdot 5$ ways.  We can then put our seven objects in order in $7!$ ways.  We then divide by $7$ because each order can be rotated to start with any object.  That gives $7!\cdot 6 \cdot 5$.

For b, we can just compute the total number of orders and subtract the answer to a.  There are $9!$ orders that start with a given car, so the answer is $9!-7!\cdot 6 \cdot 5$

Comment: You're right I was missing a lot of configurations with my thought. Your results are correct but sorry for my ignorance but I didn't understood your thought. I'm not a native English speaker and understanding maths in English is even more difficult than speaking it. Could you please be a little more analytic ?

Comment: What are you having trouble with?  Attaching a T to each P seems to me like what you were doing and makes sure you don't have two Ps together.

Comment: Now i got it that phrase is equivalent to $\frac{7!}(4!}$ . Very nice answer, thanks once again.